# Fetch data from a single table with some conditions?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am making a skill sharing website for a project.Tables in database are as follows:

1. users(id,name,email,password)
2. skills(id,skillname)
3. haveskills(id,user_id,skill_id)
      `{user_id references id in users and skill_id references id in skills}`
4. wantskills(id,user_id,skill_id)
      `{user_id references id in users and skill_id references id in skills}`
5. friends(id,user_id1,user_id2)
     `{say user with id 1 and 3 are friends then I have two rows first:user_id1=1,user_id2=3;second:user_id1=3,user_id2=1}`

When a user is logged in I have these infos:His

```
id,haveskill_id(hid),wantskill_id(wid).
```

I want sql query for all the users id whose

```
haveskill_id=wid,wantskill_id=wid and are NOT friends.
```

Edit:My query which fulfills first two conditions but I am having problem with third condition:

```
SELECT A.id FROM users A JOIN haveskills B 
 ON (A.id=B.user_id And B.skill_id='$wantskill_id') 
 JOIN wantskills C 
 ON (A.id=C.user_id AND C.skill_id='$haveskill_id');
```

Comment: Do you mean, all the other users who whose haveskill_id=wid and wantskill_id=wid and are not friends with the logged in user? Please edit your question to make what you want clear.

Comment: All other users whose [haveskill_id=wantskill_id of logged in user(i.e. wid)],[wantskill_id=haveskill_id of logged in user(i.e hid)] and are NOT friends.

Comment: Please write an entire clear sentence and edit it into your question.

Comment: I have edited the comment.Your comment mentions everything right except wantskill_id=hid.

Comment: Between your question and your comments and my comments there are five fragmented incomplete cross-referencing descriptions. Please write one clear one.